# Understanding some tabu code

Tags: color, tabu

I'm catching up on LaTeX after a period away.

Herewith part of a programme:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
 \usepackage{tabu,multirow,hyperref,colortbl,xcolor}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{tabu}
 {|>{\columncolor[named]{lightgray}}c|X[l]X[r]|X[l]X[r]|}
 \end{tabu}
 \end{document}
```

Line 5 is what's the matter. This is what's wrong:

`[named]` implies a list of "set" colours. If they're based on the RGB system, the list must be locatable somewhere. Correct?

`|X[l]X[r]|` means a cell with 2 entries, one aligned left, one right. Correct?

I don't know what this means.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Sigur, if you edited this, many thanks. I'm not sure what happened to this posting. All I can say is that it didn't leave in the form it was received.

Comment: I wouldn't bother trying to understand `tabu` because I would not use it. The package author has promised an update without backwards compatibility. Meanwhile, major bugs will not be fixed. Unless you like having documents suddenly break, requiring you to update the syntax of every table using `tabu`, the package cannot be recommended.

Answer (score 2):

The basic format is:

```
\columncolor[<color model>]{<color>} [<left overhang>][<right overhang>]
```

The first argument (or first two if the optional argument is used) are standard
color package arguments, as used by \color.

```
\color[<model>]{<specification>}
```

E.g. you could choose RGB. But have a look [here.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors)
The last two arguments control how far the panel overlaps past the widest entry in the column. [see here,p.1f](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/colortbl/colortbl.pdf)

```
|X[l]X[r]|
```

Yes, you are quite right. In a tabu or tabularx environment the X is used for variable width. AFIK [l] is  aviliable in tabu only and it's defining the alignment. You can take a look at the [tabu doc on page 10](http://ftp.fernuni-hagen.de/ftp-dir/pub/mirrors/www.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/tabu/tabu.pdf). There are some more alignment specifications.